# SIGKILL when using Game Center on iPhone Simulator, everything works fine on device

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator, sigkill

I'm using Game Center to report achievements and scores when different things happen in my game. The problem is that sometimes (quite often, really) on the iPhone Simulator the app crashes a second or so after reporting achievement or score to Game Center. This never happens on the actual device, but on the simulator it's like 8 from 10 times.

Did anyone here have this problem?

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Does the debugger give you a stack trace?  If so, could you please post it?